# How to detect multiple shakes?

Tags: java, android, shake

I am trying to make an app that will respond differently based on how many times the user shakes the device.  Specifically, the camera and a browser.  Here is my code:

```
package com.example.vikin.servicetest;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class BackgoundService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
private SensorManager senSensorManager;
private Sensor senAccelerometer;
private long lastUpdate = 0;
private float last_x, last_y, last_z;
private static final int SHAKE_THRESHOLD = 600;
float speed;
float distance;
int shakeCount = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer(true);

public BackgoundService() {
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
    Sensor mySensor = sensorEvent.sensor;

    if (mySensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
        float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
        float y = sensorEvent.values[1];
        float z = sensorEvent.values[2];

        long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if ((curTime - lastUpdate) > 10) {
            long diffTime = (curTime - lastUpdate);
            lastUpdate = curTime;

            speed = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z) / diffTime * 10000;
            distance = Math.abs(x + y + z - last_x - last_y - last_z);
            if (speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                //Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                //Intent intent1 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");
                //startActivity(intent);
                for(long i = 0; i < 20; i++){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(speed > SHAKE_THRESHOLD) {
                        shakeCount++;
                    }
                }
            }

            last_x = x;
            last_y = y;
            last_z = z;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    senSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    senAccelerometer = senSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    senSensorManager.registerListener(this, senAccelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Terminated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void countShakes() {
    if(shakeCount == 0) {
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                switch (shakeCount) {
                    case 2:
                        Intent intent1 = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.android.chrome");
                        startActivity(intent1);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    default:

                        break;
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
        if (speed < 100) {
            shakeCount++;
        }

}


}
```

When I test this on my device, it either won't open anything, or it will open the wrong application.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to using a library to detect shakes, https://github.com/square/seismic is really easy to use and works perfectly. Here is an example from their sample app. You just start the shake detector and then do something in the hearShake() method.

```
package com.squareup.seismic.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.squareup.seismic.ShakeDetector;
import static android.view.Gravity.CENTER;
import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

public class Demo extends Activity implements ShakeDetector.Listener {
  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) 
    getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    ShakeDetector sd = new ShakeDetector(this);
    sd.start(sensorManager);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setGravity(CENTER);
    tv.setText("Shake me, bro!");
    setContentView(tv, new LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
  }

  @Override public void hearShake() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Don't shake me, bro!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

}
```

Comment: I'm using it in my current app and right now in my build.gradle (Module:app) dependencies I have
`compile 'com.squareup:seismic:1.0.2'` 
Let me know if you still get an error on it after trying that

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  Is there a documentation page I can visit for future reference?

Comment: By the looks of it, seismic only has the sample app to go off of, but you can figure out everything you need to by looking through the code in their repository. Also you can look at the shake detector class in their library to see the methods available to you. Also, don't forget to call stop() on the shake detector in the onPause() method of your activity to make sure you release the sensor.